# xinetd port forwarding causes HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() to always return 127.0.0.1

Tags: centos, port-forwarding, xinetd

We're attempting to identify where specific requests are coming from inside our Java application. We have changed the log files to include the IP address and we're using `httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` to get that remote address.

When using xinetd to forward external requests on port 443 to an internal port our application server is listening on (e.g. 8999), `getRemoteAddr()` always returns 127.0.0.1. If we remove xinetd from the stack, we get the correct address.

Note that the `X-Forwarded-For` header does not get populated either.

Is there any way to continue to use xinetd to port forward without it stripping out the requestor's IP address?

Our setup:

```
service https
{
    disable = no
    flags = REUSE
    socket_type = stream
    wait = no
    user = root
    port = 443
    protocol = tcp
    redirect = localhost 8999
    log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer, your java app see just the xinetd server from localhost.

This cannot be done by xinetd alone. Use a proxy server to get the full features of headers and etc.

Apparently is the same problem: [tomcat6 behind xinetd - real client ip](https://serverfault.com/questions/418411/tomcat6-behind-xinetd-real-client-ip)

Answer (score 0):

Your server stack may be buggy or outdated. On my server (3.19.0-41-generic 14.04.2-Ubuntu, xinetd 2.3.15 libwrap loadavg) xinetd **does** forward the needed header no problem. I would propose to upgrade the server stack. You can get the xinetd version with

```
xinetd -version
```

Also check if you have configured the [RemoveIpValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html) on Tomcat properly. For the configuration like yours, conf/server.xml should contain something like

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
    remoteIpProxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
    remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
    internalProxies="127\.0\.0\.1" 
    protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```